# Codename one retrieving location at regular time intervals

Tags: location, codenameone

I am trying to get location coordinates using code name one using the following code
*loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();*

I am invoking the above method to run at regular intervals by calling it inside a *UITimer*. The problem is I am not able to get the accurate location using the above code. Even though this method is called for every 10 seconds I see change in coordinates only at 4-5 minutes interval. I am testing by carrying the device in vehicle which is moving constantly. I have tried using *getCurrentLocationSync()* but no luck. Any suggestions on improving the location accuracy?

Comment: Is this happening on Simulator or real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must never do location polling as it will kill the battery and doesn't work properly on devices. If you want to get location updates on a running application just use location listener with [setLocationListener](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/location/LocationManager.html#setLocationListener-com.codename1.location.LocationListener-).

It will get invoked as you move around.

If you want to get location events in the background when your app is minimized then you will need the [background location support](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html) (geofencing).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Shai...will give a try